# How long will my deep cycle batteries run stuff for through an inverter?

Tags: inverter

so ive got 4x crown cr-225 deep cycle batteries saying the following specs,

Voltage 6v
A.h. Rating 225 (20hr)
A.h. Rating 171 (5hr)

I've got these linked in series and parallel to give a 12v system with twice the punch,

Have done some calculations based on peoples sums on other forum threads but I'm not sure why my batteries have to different a.h. Ratings so some info on that would be handy, and the sum and answer for continously running something 100w for example. Also I know investors only have about a 85% efficency rate but let's forget that for now to keep things simple for me...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!  Thanks

Comment: Apparently so Brian, so why do my batteries have 2 different amp hour ratings stated on them?

Comment: And also wouldnt it be 450ah as I have them linked in series and parallel?

Comment: Not familiar with the electrical term, 'punch'.

Comment: @gbarry, The derivative of velocity is accelleration. The deriviative of accelleration is jerk. The next derivatives are snap, crackle, and pop. So maybe "punch" is the derivative of pop?

Answer (score 2):

The 225 Ah rating assumes the battery is discharged over 20 hours, while the 171 Ah rating assumes the batery is discharged over 5 hours.  The faster you discharge a bettery, the less energy you will get from it.

If your four 6 volt batteries are connected to produce 12 volts, the combined battery bank will have a capacity of 450 Ah (20 hour rate) or 342 Ah (5 hour).

Your 100 Watt load will draw about 8.3 amps, which is well under the 20 hour rate, so we can use the 20 hour rating of 450 Ah.

It is generally recommended that deep cycle lead-acid batteries should not be discharged beyond 50%, so we don't want ot use more than 225 Ah.  At 8.3 amps, we can run your 100 watt load for 225/8.3 = 27 hours.

Comment: Just to emphasize, the batteries WILL run the load longer than 27 hours. But you should take steps to avoid letting that happen because it will be bad for the batteries.